# Crystal Reports: Missing bars on a chart

Tags: crystal-reports

In my continued effort to work the chart, I am using the following formula on a chart.

```
if {Command.count} = Maximum ({Command.count}) then Black
else if {Command.count} = Minimum ({Command.count}) then Black
else {Command.count}
```

Also tried,

```
if {Command.count} = Maximum ({Command.count}) then crBlack
else if {Command.count} = Minimum ({Command.count}) then crBlack
else {Command.count}
```

With the above formula, the chart shows every bar according to the data, except for the max and mix bars. It's so weird that the chart is only excluding these two. Is the color wrong on the formula?

I also created separate max and min values with the formula like,

```
If {Command.count} = maximum ({Command.count}) then 1 else 0
If {Command.count} = minimum ({Command.count}) then 1 else 0
```

Then tried,

```
if Maximum ({Command.count}) = {@MaxValue} then crblack
else if {Command.count} = {@MinValue} then black
else {Command.count}
```

The above formula shows all the bars, but the chart does not change colors for the max and min.... Gahhh!!!

[image]

Comment: From looking back at the chart on your previous question, those look like the min and max bars that you wanted to highlight.  Try undoing whatever was done to highlight the min/max bars and see if that restores the missing bars.  If it does, then the issue is in how your were attempting to highlight them.

Comment: If I don't use the formula, then all the bars are back, but I need the max and min in different colors... This is frustrating.

Comment: You may want to update your original question about highlighting the min/max bars with this if you haven't already done so.  If I have any ideas I will keep an eye on both questions to try and help.  So far, I've been unable to replicate the behavior in a way that allows me to understand what is happening.